NLTK Conditional Frequency Distribution with Aggregation
I'm trying to write an NLTK ConditionalFreqDist with some aggregated fields based on data from the fileid.
Basically, I have a corpus of documents with fileids consisting of a DATE-TITLE format, e.g., '2024-10-23 TitleName'.
Multiple fileids can share the same date.
I'm trying to write a conditional frequency distribution that:

Finds the frequency of target words in each file,
Shows me that frequency,

But, that also:

Aggregates the wordcount for each month (based on the fileid), instead of displaying it for each individual document.

I have the following code, but right now I think it's returning the aggregate len() of all fileids for that year-month:
    cfd = ConditionalFreqDist(
        (target, file)
        for target in ['Apple','Microsoft']
        for file in corpus.fileids()
        for word in corpus.words(file))

Any help or suggestions appreciated.

can you also provide a sample of the data that you're working?

You should count each target word per month rather than returning the count of file IDs.
Like this,
cfd = ConditionalFreqDist(
    (month, word)
    for month, word_counts in monthly_word_counts.items()
    for word, count in word_counts.items()
    for _ in range(count)
)

